# Showing custom fields on Order Page in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I used a function to add a custom field to order meta with the action `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta`. I can see the custom fields on the admin page, but I cannot make those custom fields appeared in the order page of the website.

Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'time_field_update_order_meta' );

function time_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( $_POST['time_1'] ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Time 1', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['time_1'] ) );
    }
    if ( $_POST['time_2'] ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Time 2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['time_2'] ) );
    }
}
```

Is there another action or filter that I can add on my `functions.php` to display those custom fields too?

Comment: Here's a [tutorial](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/) that I wrote on adding/saving/displaying custom checkout data.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a similar function like the one shown here on github: https://gist.github.com/woogist/6267983

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Time 1', true );
    echo get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Time 2', true );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't display the fields :(

Comment: Try adding a test echo and make sure it's hooked in correctly. The order on this page looks different. http://hookr.io/actions/woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address/

Comment: I have an `echo 'hi'` for testing purposes, but still it isn't showing anything.